# Unable to run for different browsers using --Variable of Robot Framework

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

In the Keywords.robot i have specified the Browser as variable and assigned to chrome, but when i tried to run from the terminal using the below command

C:\Users\rajre\PycharmProjects\Automation>robot --variable Browser:firefox TestCases\LoginTest.robot

throws error as **"SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities "**

**Note:** I have kept the geckodriver.exe at location  C:\Users\rajre\PycharmProjects\Automation\venv\Scripts

**LoginKeywords.robot:**

```html
*** Settings ***
Library     Selenium2Library
Variables  ../PageObjects/Locaters.py

*** Variables ***
${AppUrl}   https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx
${Browser}  chrome

*** Keywords ***
Open my Browser
    [Arguments]    ${AppUrl}   ${Browser}
    open browser    ${AppUrl}   ${Browser}
    maximize browser window

Input UserName
  [Arguments]  ${Username}
  input text  ${txt_loginUserName}  ${Username}

Input Pwd
  [Arguments]  ${Password}
  input text  ${txt_loginPassword}  ${Password}

Click Login Button
  click button  ${btn_Login}

Verify Message
   should contain  Password cannot be empty  Password cannot be empty
   should contain  Username cannot be empty  Username cannot be empty
   should contain  Invalid credentials   Invalid credentials
   should contain  Dashboard  Dashboard
```

LoginTest.robot

```html
 
*** Settings ***
Library   Selenium2Library
Resource  ../Resources/LoginKeywords.robot
Library  DataDriver  ../TestData/LoginTestData.xlsx

Suite Setup  Open my Browser  ${AppUrl}   ${Browser}
Suite Teardown  Close Browser
Test Template   Login Validation
*** Test Cases ***

LoginTest
    Login Validation

*** Keywords ***
Login Validation
    [Arguments]     ${Username}   ${Password}
    Input UserName  ${Username}
    sleep  1
    Input Pwd   ${Password}
    sleep  1
    Click Login Button
    sleep  1
    Verify Message
```

LoginTest.robot

I have tried this way too, but no luck

Suite Setup  Open my Browser  ${AppUrl}   browser=${Browser}

C:\Users\rajre\PycharmProjects\Automation>robot --variable browser:firefox TestCases\LoginTest.robot

Comment: It's a bit confusing to me. What drivers do you have? What versions of drivers and browsers do you have? They need to match, check the driver documentation pages. Also, if you want to run in Chrome, you need to have a driver for Chrome as well as Chrome. Similarly for Firefox. Drivers need to be in `PATH`. Can you confirm you have done all this?

Comment: If the problem is with the `open browser` keyword, you can remove the definition of the other keywords and make an example that is a single file. That will make it easier for people to try out your code.

Answer (score 0):

**Open Browser** keyword will find a browser driver on your environment variables, you may add your drivers there. Or, you can use its optional parameter ***"executable-path"***

So it goes like this for Chrome

```
Open Browser    https://www.google.com/   Chrome  executable_path=C:/chromedriver.exe
```

For Firefox

```
Open Browser    https://www.google.com/   Firefox  executable_path=C:/geckodriver.exe
```

You can have different keywords for that or just also pass the executable_path on your **[Arguments]**

Answer (score -1):

The `geckodriver` is only used for Firefox Browser, and you have specified the Browser as variable and assigned to Chrome, This will definitely not work . Download the latest `chromedriver` from [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: You can specify browser as a variable. You can set that variable to Chrome. Neither of these is a problem.

Comment: Yes i agree. But i don't think he has installed chrome driver!